# Binary data returned from IWinHttpRequest are altered, unable to convert Variant to array of bytes

Tags: inno-setup, ole, pascalscript, winhttprequest

In my setup scenario at the end of the installation process each client downloads application key from the server. The file consists of ~64 random bytes, binary, non-encoded. It should be stored in configuration file in installation directory.

The setup is handled with Inno Setup, which calls key generation procedure during `CurStepChanged` event. OLE `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` is created, POST request containing client data is sent, and binary response should be received. The response is extracted using `WinHttpReq.ResponseText` and stored to file using `SaveStringToFile`.

However the resulting file differs from this sent from the server. For example data logged on the server side:

`5a7868256a890e25735f431351f023c143f0cc397e6ec01e8a81806564eaa9f4fc8a005d9035c18fa32f95daaeff34955f3f6e4bfc5051bd33a522cc2aaddac8f29a1031dcb23728250c4f0a73db6a5bcc64e1ddef71a6`

is received as

`5a7868256a3f0e25735f4313513f23c1433f49397e6e411e3f813f656465a9f4fc3f005d9035c13f4c2f3fdaae79343f5f3f6e4bfc505131335922492aadda456f3f1031dc323728250c4f0a73556a5b4964e1dd6971a6`

(for example 6th byte is different). There are no such problems is data does not contain non-ascii data.

My first idea was that at some point encoding/decoding of the binary data to text modifies some bytes. I wanted to use `IWinHttpRequest::ResponseBody` to access the data in binary version instead of the text version. Passing this property results in target file being filled with `?` characters instead of the data. Only ascii characters were preserved.

I also tried converting `ResponseBody` to pascal array of bytes, but received `Type Mismatch` error. The `VarType` for `ResponseBody` returns dec 8209, which maps to `array` and `byte`, but assigning `ResponseBody` to `array of byte` leads to the error above.

What is the correct way to store binary HTTP result to file in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us your code, so it's difficult to say what problem you may have.

Though I guess that you have passed `WinHttpReq.ResponseText` (wide `string`) directly to `SaveStringToFile` (which takes `AnsiString`). This involves an implicit UTF-16 to ANSI encoding conversion, what causes loss or conversion of some characters.

This works just fine, in *Unicode* version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6):

```pascal
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  S: string;
  I: Integer;
  Data: AnsiString;
begin
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'https://www.example.com/key.dat', False);
  WinHttpReq.Send('');
  if WinHttpReq.Status <> 200 then
  begin
    Log('HTTP Error: ' + IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status) + ' ' + WinHttpReq.StatusText);
  end
    else
  begin
    S := WinHttpReq.ResponseText;
    SetLength(Data, Length(S));
    for I := 1 to Length(S) do
    begin
      Data[I] := S[I];
    end;

    SaveStringToFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\key.dat'), Data, False);
  end;
end;
```

---

*The code might be inefficient for downloading large binary files. But for 64 bytes it's just ok. For larger files, one probably [can use `ADODB.Stream` class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13532969/850848).*